# Delete specific duplicate values ​in the same row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

| en | ko |
| --- | --- |
| Fetishistic transvestism(F65.1) | 물품음란성 의상도착증(F65.1) |
| Obsessive-compulsive disorder(F42.-) | 강박장애(F42.-) |
| Conduct disorders(F91.-) | 행동장애(F91.-) |
| Schizophrenia(F20.-) | 조현병(F20.-) |

I want to remove duplicate values ​​in the same row in this data frame.

| en | ko |
| --- | --- |
| Fetishistic transvestism | 물품음란성 의상도착증 |
| Obsessive-compulsive disorder | 강박장애 |
| Conduct disorders | 행동장애 |
| Schizophrenia | 조현병 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you can use `difflib`:

```
import difflib
import pandas as pd

def remove_common_postfix(row: pd.Series, column1: str, column2: str):
    """
    Remove common postfix of 2 columns in 1 row
    :param row: a dataframe row
    :param column1: column name 1
    :param column2: column name 2
    :return: a dataframe row
    """
    a = row[column1]
    b = row[column2]
    sequence_matcher = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, a, b)

    match = sequence_matcher.find_longest_match(0, len(a), 0, len(b))
    row[column1], row[column2] = a[:match.a], b[:match.b]

    return row


if __name__ == "__main__":
    values = [["Fetishistic transvestism(F65.1)", "물품음란성 의상도착증(F65.1)"],
              ["Obsessive-compulsive disorder(F42.-)", "강박장애(F42.-)"]]

    df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=["en", "ko"])
    print(df)
    df = df.apply(lambda row: remove_common_postfix(row, "en", "ko"), axis=1)
    print(df)
```

The output seems good:

[image]